# MongoDB and Mongoose databases not connecting across directories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a web server running, that uses mongoDB to store posts created on the website.

I would like to use a separate script to manage some things on the site, however for some reason I can't seem to get the code working across directories.

The website is running in /home/username/program/

I want my utility script to reside in /home/myname/utils/

This is currently the script I have:

```js
#!/usr/bin/nodejs

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_name',{useNewUrlParser:true});
var chat = require('/home/username/project/lib/models/chat');

chat.findOne(function(err,doc) { 
        console.log(err,doc);
});
```

This code works, and gets data, but *only* if the file it's written it resides in /home/username/project/lib/.

If the file is in /home/mynameutil/ then it doesn't get any data at all. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate, because you don't start your project on `/home/username` so your program shared same instance, If you want to create something across the folder considers using workspaces.

Some tools make it easy to create workspaces like [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) and [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/en/workspaces) with this your code can be run in the same instance and share same `node_modules`. So you can use it across folder

Comment: So basically, all mongo DB related code that wants to use a projects database HAS to be in the same directory workspace? Odd, but ok.

Comment: Yeah @Alexwall, that's how the packge.json and `node_modules` thing works. CMIIW here but I use `workspace` to share code between project. Or if in these case a database you can just query it without knowing the models is okay. You just need a database connection on the `home/myutils`